# Strange behavior of TOP 1 clause sql server

Tags: sql-server, query, order-by, collation, top

I have a SQL Server database and restored it on another server on a different machine. Now I run following same query on both DBs which produces same below result set.

```
select person_id, visit_id, verification_code, mobileNo, created_date
from person
order by verification_code, created_date DESC
```

[image]

But when I add TOP 1 clause to the above query, original DB shows the 2nd row (ignores first row)

```
select TOP 1 person_id, visit_id, verification_code, mobileNo, created_date
from person
order by verification_code, created_date DESC
```

[image]

while restored DB shows first row

[image]

I thought it might be due to different collation, but I checked both servers have same collation.

Comment: Try adding `with ties` to the top clause.

Comment: For deterministic results, the specified `ORDER BY` columns must be unique. Try `ORDER BY verification_code, created_date DESC, person_id`.

Comment: hanks for reply, my original question was 'why different behavior despite same data & same query'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike D. has provided an [answer on how SQL Server sorts data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012) that might help you understand what is it about the **deterministic result** you see on some comments.

The [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) of the `ORDER BY` doc says:

> ASC | DESC
>  Specifies that the values in the specified column should be
> sorted in ascending or descending order. ASC sorts from the lowest
> value to highest value. DESC sorts from highest value to lowest value.
> ASC is the default sort order. Null values are treated as the lowest
> possible values.

All the `NULL` values went to the top of your result for being the lowest possible values and since the `create_date` for those rows are all the same, according to the set theory, it doesn't make any difference which one of the four `NULL` values are presented first.

Comment: Original DB is on SQL Server 2014, while same DB is restored on SQL Server 2017. This might be the issue that same query on same data fetch different TOP 1 row on different versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @user1543848, Yes, the difference between one engine and the other could be one more thing influencing on the different result, but is it clear for you now that none of the results are wrong? In fact you could have four different result for that query considering that sample data and they should not surprise you. It's the expected behavior. Even if you would run that same query repeatedly only on your SQL Server 2014, you could not expect to get the same result all the time for a nondeterministic request like that.

Comment: Here's a simple way to see it: imagine I give you ten U$100 bills and ask you to order them by value and give me the one at the top. All the bills are of U$100 so you put them on the order you prefer and give me the one at the top. You did what I asked, yet, if later I shuffle those same ten bills and ask you to order them by value and give me the top one again, chances are 1/10 that you're gonna give me the same bill against 9/10 that it's gonna be another one. How do I know that it's not the same bill? They all have a unique serial number, but I didn't mention it on my request to you.

Answer (score 1):

But the data in your order by clause doesn't provide any ordering

verification_code is null

and all values for

created_date are the same

you have to give the engine a little bit to work with

Comment: updated result set, please

Comment: Verification_Code is null, therefore ordering is "nondeterministic". Now it would depend on PK, clustered index etc, but nondeterministic.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my original question was 'why different behavior despite same data & same query'

Comment: The answer is in the comments, @user1543848. Same **non-determenistic** query. Different results are expected.